# Incorrect csv file from impala output

Tags: sql, excel, impala

[Snapshot of the "csv" file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfKXR.png)

So I have the table created by impala saved as csv file using the following code:
impala-shell -B -o output.csv --output_delimiter=',' -q "select * from foo" which is supposed to return a csv file, but it didnt. 
Anyone help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output file you have is *close* to a CSV file, except that it is using pipes instead of commas.  To import this into Excel, just use the wizard and select pipe (`|`) as the delimiter.

I'm not sure what went wrong with your Impala export, but you should be able to work with what you already have.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that. But if you look carefully at the first line of the excel, there is only one column for each row, which means it is not separated by "|". Not sure if I understand this correctly.

Comment: This is because Excel is detecting that each line only has one column of text.  If you follow my suggestion and use the wizard to import the file, you may select `|` as the delimiter, and immediately you should see the separate columns you are expecting.